# drag n drop table rows from 1 to another and save content in database

Tags: javascript

Please help me out, my problem is as follows

in *javascript* `redips-drag.js`

there's a line in one function which is as follows

```
if (tbl_cell.childNodes[d].tagName === 'DIV')
{
 query += 'p[]=' + tbl_cell.childNodes[d].id 
                 + '_' + t + '_' + r + '_' + c + '_'
                 + tbl_cell.childNodes[d].innerHTML +'&';
}
```

in `multiple-parameters.php` which is used to input data in mysql code is as follows

```
list($id, $tbl, $row, $col, $val) = explode('_', $p);
echo $val;
```

it prints me this

> ASP.NET Sharepoint **Dropdown**

where ASP.NET Sharepoint are my table values and Dropdown is a select list where in selected value 1 in the table it still returns me the select dropdown when i echo the $val variable it should have printed me

> ASP.NET Sharepoint **1**

remember i m dragging dropping table rows from one to another and then trying to save data in database.

```
   <tr class="rd">
     <td class="rowhandler"><div class="drag row"></div></td>
 <td align="center"><div id="d1"><input type="hidden" name="sname<? echo $i; ?>" value="<?echo $temp;?>" /><? echo $temp ?></div></td>
     <td align="center"><div id="d2"><input type="hidden" name="sdesc<? echo $i; ?>" value="<?echo $temp1;?>" /><? echo $temp1 ?></div></td>
     <td align="center">
     <div id="d3"> 
      <select name="selfRating<? echo $i; ?>" id="selfRating<? echo $i; ?>">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="1" <?php if (isset($_POST['selfRating'.$i]) && $_POST['selfRating'.$i] == "1") {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >1</option>
       <option value="2" <?php if (isset($_POST['selfRating'.$i]) && $_POST['selfRating'.$i] == "2") {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >2</option>
       <option value="3" <?php if (isset($_POST['selfRating'.$i]) && $_POST['selfRating'.$i] == "3") {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >3</option>
       <option value="4" <?php if (isset($_POST['selfRating'.$i]) && $_POST['selfRating'.$i] == "4") {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >4</option>
       <option value="5" <?php if (isset($_POST['selfRating'.$i]) && $_POST['selfRating'.$i] == "5") {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >5</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to go on here. Please include a copy of the contents of the DIV in question.

Comment: is this what u mean by the contents of DIV ?

Comment: In which of those divs (d1, d2, d3) could you get the content 'ASP.NET Sharepoint' ?

Comment: d1 gives me ASP.NET d2 gives me Sharepoint and d3 should give me value 1 instead of which its returning me whole select drop down

Comment: The code tbl_cell.childNodes[d].innerHTML will give you the full contents of the cell. If you want the selected value of the dropdown you will have to modify the javascript in redips-drag.js.

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery? it would make a solution easier.

Comment: james i have modified that content too as if (tbl_cell.childNodes[d].tagName === 'DIV') { // and yes, it should be uppercase
        var select = tbl_cell.childNodes[d].innerHTML;
        var select = $(select).html();
        var rating = $(select).val();
   query += 'p[]=' + tbl_cell.childNodes[d].id + '_' + t + '_' + r + '_' + c + '_' + rating +'&';
       } it gives me values as undefinedundefinedundefined instead of ASP.NET Sharepoint 1

Comment: i have used jquery but then instead of displaying values as ASP.NET Sharepoint 1 it displays values as undefinedundefinedundefined the jquery i used is pasted above

Comment: Hi Prashant - you've indicated I solved your problem so please click the Accept This Answer button and give me an upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the code you quoted in *redips-drag.js* was inside a loop over the `childNodes` of `tbl_cell`, using var `d` . Replace it all with this:

```
var myDiv = $(tbl_cell).children('div');
var mySelect = myDiv.find('select');
var interp = mySelect.length ? mySelect.val() : myDiv.html();

query += 'p[]=' + myDiv.attr('id') 
             + '_' + t + '_' + r + '_' + c + '_'
             + interp +'&';
```

Comment: Really thanks a lot friend for solving this problem hope i took right action to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are getting a dropdown instead of selected value in that dropdown is because you are using tbl_cell.childNodes[d].innerHTML.

You should store the innerhtml in a variable which is your dropdown: (I am using jquery here)

var select = tbl_cell.childNodes[d].innerHTML;

var select = $(select).html();

var selected_value = $(select).val();

and then pass selected_value variable in your query:

query += 'p[]=' + tbl_cell.childNodes[d].id 
                 + '*' + t + '*' + r + '*' + c + '*'
                 + selected_value +'&';

Comment: dear amit i tried the above code but when i echo my php variable its showing me `undefinedundefinedundefined` which should be `ASP.NET Sharepoint 1`